# Slow response to database write from php

Tags: php, mysql, tcl, wamp

I have my PHP scripts running on the WAMP server. 
Here's what i am doing

1. PHP script A that queries the database and gets a set of rows (I have set the set_time_limit (0) // unlimited time for the script to execute )
2. Based on the result set I execute a tcl script for each row of the result set
3. The TCL script takes about a minute to execute , it also inserts some data to the same database
4. Now simultaneously when the TCL script is executing  , if i execute another PHP script that writes in to the database , I am not able to do it as the response time is too slow. It infact waits for the PHP script A/TCL script to complete
5. However during this time, reads from the database is fine and quick

Does anyone has any suggestions ?

Regards,
Mithun

Comment: What engine are you using for these tables? Do any of the scripts in question work with Transactions?

Comment: If you're using myisam tables, mysql locks the whole table while writes to the table occur. You're probably doing some long running update or instert statements, or otherwise explicittly lock the table in the code. Or you're using innodb and have long running transactions

Comment: @nos, you should've make it as an answer, this is most likely the reason.

Comment: I am using MyIsam engine . I think the problem is with TCL taking time to execute. even if I don't write to the database from TCL . The PHP script waits for the TCL to complete before writing to the database. 

Please note that I using PHP's exec() to call the TCL script . and this is in a loop of rows retrieved from the database. i.e iam calling the TCL script some 7 times (for 7 rows --just a eg).

Comment: If you're using exec, ofcourse php waits until it's finished, that's what exec does.

Comment: Ok I debugged more .I am accessing a session variable at the start of the PHP script A. Because of this it is getting slow. If I remove the session variable , the the other PHP script is able to write to the database while the TCL script is executing . Any thoughts why this is happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Session cannot be shared by concurrent scripts. Any new requests which try to `session_start()` will hang at this point waiting for the previous script end.

As your script is taking undetermined time to end, its a good idea to `session_write_close()` right after obtaining all information it needs from the $_SESSION superglobal, so concurrent requests won't hang anymore.