# Cookie value is not being retrived properly

Tags: php

I am setting a cookie in a PHP script which also has some html ,  the first line is setcookie function as required.

```
<?php 
setcookie("user", "xyz", time()+3600);
?>
<html>
------ some html tags 
</html>
```

In other PHP script where am trying to access , i get a blank value . 
$user=$_COOKIE["user"];

Can anyone tell me why is this happening ?

Comment: You have cookies enabled, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good practice to store sensitive information in cookies like this. Cookies may be edited by the user, so here he could set his "user" cookie to get being recognized as any user he wants. Its a better practice to use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) instead. With sessions you can safely and easily bind any sensitive information to this specific user using the $_SESSION superglobal.

Comment: I was using sessions .But I had some problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316054/slow-response-to-database-write-from-php)
Thats why i am using cookie now.

Comment: I have an answer for this other question, I'll be writing it right now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316054/slow-response-to-database-write-from-php/1317534#1317534

Answer (score 2):

Your browser has cookies enabled, right?

What does var_dump( $_COOKIE['user'] ); print exactly? NULL, false?

Comment: Yes cookie is enabled. Infact the value is set , I can see it in the option/privacy tab in firefox . But the value is not acessible.
var_dump( $_COOKIE['user'] ); gives me NULL.

Comment: can you paste more code? you're not showing the whole script. this is one file, two files? on the same server, not subdomains right?

Comment: Ok . I am setting the cookie at http://mydomain/home.php 
and i am trying to access it on http://mydomain/cl/base/test.php . Is this possible ?

Comment: Try specifying more arguments..

);
setcookie ("user", "xyz", time() + 3600, "/", ".mydomain.com");